# Can I get bluetooth music enabled in my 2009 BMW 528i?

Tags: bmw, audio

I just bought a 2009 BMW 528i. It’s my understanding that the car doesn’t support A2DP which is a technology that would allow me to connect to my stereo system via Bluetooth and stream music wirelessly. Currently, I have a dongle which connects from the dock connector on my phone and splits off into a USB and 3.5 mm jack in the car’s armrest. I’m assuming the USB interface allows for iDrive control of the stored music while the 3.5 mm handles the music stream.

The car does pair over Bluetooth with my iPhone in order to make hands free calls without the phone being plugged in but what would be required if I wanted to be able to just pair the phone over Bluetooth with my car, switch to the AUX stereo input, and play music without having to plug it in?

Comment: If you go with an aftermarket radio option, ensure they know how to bypass the radio in your optical loop. If not the whole entertainment system might be down.

Comment: Grateful if you could advise what happens to the phone calls when I'd use A2DP receiver for the music? would the iPhone connect to the receiver for music and to the car for calls?

Answer (score 3):

HTC offers an accessory, [Bluetooth Stereo Clip](http://www.htc.com/us/accessories/htc-bluetooth-stereoclip/). It allows for wireless streaming from device to the car’s AUX jack.

I use this in my 2009 528i. It plugs right into the AUX jack, and a short USB cable plugs in right next to it, providing power. It’s battery powered, but charges via the USB, and it connects automatically when you get into the car.

Perfect solution. Looked all over before I found it.

Answer (score 1):

as far as I can tell with this radio you may have an adapter in the glove box area.  However this may need to be installed. This would interface for play back and bluetooth for the calls.

personally I would go all aftermarket stereo and junk the stock.

Answer (score 1):

You need an A2DP receiver, these typically output to a 3.5mm male audio plug. A quick google search will yield many options. All require power of some sort. Some are rechargeable or can be charged by USB, which I would imagine would be best for your application.

one option at newegg: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA07Y0AG5963

Answer (score 1):

I second mac’s reply. A couple things to keep in mind when buying an A2DP receiver:

1. Make sure the receiver turns on automatically when you start the car.
2. Look for a receiver that can pair with more than one phone, i.e. if you have a passenger that wants to play music from their device.